# Ecore Reference

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

We have the XML file which contains the ecore objects.But some of the ecore objects is referencing to the other objects through reference type.So the xml will contains the path as for EX: if Class A present in Package0 referencing to Class B present in Package1  the reference type in the XML file will be string type i.e Class A contains the reference type attribute and it value will be of type String such as "Package1/Class A".But the way the model file stores the reference in different type for Ex: #//Class A,So how can i convert that String type reference to the model type reference such that the model can understand it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to think in terms of UML, with the notions of aggregation and composition.

Moreover, the reflexion you expose is a matter of design: if a string attribute must be a reference to an external string (relatively to a class), probably this attribute shall be a member of a upper class.